# PHP Echo Numbers With Letters

Tags: php, numbers

On my game, I have it to where when someone logs in, it displays their cash. It's Fetched from the database.

```
<div id="StatText">Cash: <span id="Cash">$<?php echo number_format($cash) ?></span></div>
```

Well, I updated the database for my account and gave myself $10,000,000,000,000 = 10 Trillion dollars. Well How would I make it to where a user's cash would show like this. If they had $16,500 It would display $16.5K And same with millions billions ETC. 
Example: 
$16,500 = 16.5K 
$160,500 = 160.5K 
$1,600,500 = 1.6M 
$10,000,016,500 = 10B 
$9,110,000,016,500 = 9.1T 
Nothing really showed up on Google.
Thanks For Any Help!

Comment: You search for a "Human readable" method. i write it, wait :)

Comment: u will need to develop this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Late answer) This works (you're welcome to use it) Keep the accepted answer.

```
<?php
$n = 15500000000; // echoes $15.5B
// $n = 9110000016500; // echoes $9.1T

if ($n < 1000000) {
    // Anything less than a million
    $n_format = number_format($n);
} 

else if ($n < 1000000000) {
    // Anything less than a billion
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000, 1) . 'M';
} 

else if ($n < 1000000000000) {
    // Anything less than a trillion
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000, 1) . 'B';
} 

else {
    // At least a trillion
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000000, 1) . 'T';

} 

echo "$" .$n_format;
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/116243)

*Call it my contribution*

Comment: To my fred who doesn't care about reps. **+1** and added a demo of the same.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Thanks Shankar. I truly enjoy adding my contribution to the community, especially when it comes to math related code. Thanks also for the "Demo" link :) cheers

Comment: I've got this idiot that's going around -1 my answers @ShankarDamodaran - A new "trend" as you call it. As we call these in Canada, phoque nuts.

Comment: Yeah mate that is really bad. See my [_rep chart_](http://i.imgur.com/39vx9RB.png) how horrible it looks :(

Comment: Some have no balls. I'm not sure if you know what that means, but around here that means "some have no courage" type of thing and no respect. If one is going to downvote an answer, the "least" a person could do is give a reason. Not doing so is total ignorance in my view. @ShankarDamodaran

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function bd_nice_number($n) {
    // first strip any formatting;
    $n = (0+str_replace(",","",$n));

    // is this a number?
    if(!is_numeric($n)) return false;

    // now filter it;
    if($n>1000000000000) return round(($n/1000000000000),1).' T';
    else if($n>1000000000) return round(($n/1000000000),1).' B';
    else if($n>1000000) return round(($n/1000000),1).' M';
    else if($n>1000) return round(($n/1000),1).' K';

    return number_format($n);
}
```

to get a nice number:

```
echo bd_nice_number(your_number_here);
```

Comment: 9trill displayed as  $9992.2 T

Comment: are you sure? `echo bd_nice_number(9110000016500)` shows `9.1 T`

Comment: Nvm, Your code also Worked, At first it showed wrong, Not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution, hope you like and understand that:

```
<?php
    /*
        @param $money       the money
        @param $currency    the currency label
        @param $format      Array with parameters like number_format
    */
    function human_readable_money($money, $currency = '', $format = null) {
        $suffix = '';

        // Trillions
        if($money >= 1000000000000) {
            $money  /= 1000000000000;
            $suffix = 'T';

        // Billions
        } else if($money >= 10000000000 && $money <= 1000000000000) {
            $money  /= 10000000000;
            $suffix = 'B';

        // Millions
        } else if($money >= 1000000 && $money <= 10000000000) {
            $money  /= 1000000;
            $suffix = 'M';

        // Thousand
        } else if($money >= 1000 && $money <= 1000000) {
            $money  /= 1000;
            $suffix = 'K';
        }

        if(!empty($format) && count($format) == 3) {
            $money = number_format($money, $format[0], $format[1], $format[2]);
        }

        return sprintf('%s%s%s', $currency, $money, $suffix);
    }

    // Examples
    /*
        $16,500 = 16.5K 
        $160,500 = 160.5K 
        $1,600,500 = 1.6M 
        $10,000,016,500 = 10B 
        $9,110,000,016,500 = 9.1T
    */

    $examples = array(
        16500,
        160500,
        1600500,
        10000016500,
        9110000016500
    );

    foreach($examples AS $cash) {
        printf('<div id="StatText">Cash: <span id="Cash">%s</span></div>', human_readable_money($cash, '$', array(1, '.', ',')));
    }
?>
```

Example Output: http://demo.meinchat.net/TEST/